# Report Viewer - Setting the decimal places for a textbox value

Tags: reportviewer, rdlc

I'm using Report Viewer Control (rdlc) to generate reports. One of my columns have the value

```
=AVG(Fields!Reading.Value, "CellReading_Reading")
```

I'm getting the value with 10 or more decimal places. But i want to round it off to 3 decimal places. What is the expression for doing this?

Thank you.
NLV

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
FormatNumber(AVG(Fields!Reading.Value, "CellReading_Reading"),3)
```

Comment: What if i want a string 5500 as 5,500?

Comment: Okie, i found the answer. Need to set the group digits to "true" in the same FormatNumber().

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39305134/2218697) is my answer to set 3 decimal places  without rounding off , is that correct ?

Comment: but, this changes the number to string

Answer (score 2):

1. Right-click the textbox
2. Click the number
3. Select number from the category
4. Set `Decimal Places` to 0

Answer (score 1):

cdonner's answer was great and I incorporated it myself. If you have a slightly more complicated case as I did and you want to concatenate more than 1 field from more than 1 dataset you can do it like this...

=FormatNumber(Sum(Fields!Actual_Measurement.Value, "Measured_Result"), 1) 
& " (" & 
FormatNumber(First(Fields!Allowed_Min.Value, "Measured_Result_Details"), 1) 
& " - " & 
FormatNumber(First(Fields!Allowed_Max.Value, "Measured_Result_Details"), 1) 
& ")"

An example of what is displayed here would be ...

15.3 (12 - 16)

... If Actual_Measurement = 15.3, Allowed_Min = 12 and Allowed_Max = 16

In this case 1 entry in the "Measured_Result_Details" table relates to 1 or many entries in the "Measured_Result" table. Right clicking on the box and selecting "Expression", then looking in "Datasets" my two "Items" are "Measured_Result_Details" and "Measured_Result". This may be useful to anyone who has more than 1 dataset with fields from each dataset to be displayed in 1 Text Box!

Answer (score 0):

If you want **without rounding off** use `Math.Truncate`:

```
=Math.Truncate(1000*(AVG(Fields!Reading.Value, "CellReading_Reading")))/1000
```

Reference [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17270363/how-can-i-prevent-rounding-off-in-rdlc-report) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3143657/truncate-two-decimal-places-without-rounding) post .

Hope helps.

Answer (score 0):

The **simplest approach** should be to just enter `N3` in the `format` property of the textbox.

`N` stands for the number and `C` stands for the currency

Examples:

`N0` format `123456.12` as `123,456`

`C2` format `1234.562` as `$1,234.56`

and so on ...