# Truncating in C#

Tags: c#, math

```
string input = Console.ReadLine();
decimal sum = Convert.ToDecimal(input);
if (sum >= (decimal)500.01)
{
    //40% and 8 dollars off shipping costs are taken off total amount
    decimal totalprice;
    totalprice = (sum - 8) * .60m;
    Math.Truncate(totalprice);
    Console.WriteLine("Your final cost is:${0:0.00}", totalprice);
    Console.Read();
```

The problem is, when I enter the price 598.88 dollars into my program, I should get 354.52.

The Math:

```
598.88 - 8 = 590.88. 590.88 * 60% = 354.528
```

I actually get `354.53` because C# rounds up instead of down. 
For example,

If I get an answer like `519.998`, I want it to STAY at `519.99`.
Another example, if I get an answer like `930.755` I want it to stay at `930.75`.

I looked into some answers, but `Math.Truncate` obviously doesn't work for me and using the `*100 / 100` trick didn't work either. Keep in mind I'm a new student, So, if an answer could be noob-safe, that would be nice. Thanks.

Comment: Like zerkms said use Math.Floor(), also use Decimal.TryParse to make sure the input is fine.

Comment: `Math.Truncate()` obviously can't work for you, because it doesn't do anything to its argument, it returns the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The  `* 100 / 100` works fine, you might have been using it wrong.  Try this below:

```
decimal totalprice = TruncateToTwoDigits((sum - 8) * .60m);
Console.WriteLine("Your final cost is:${0:0.00}", totalprice);

... 

private static decimal TruncateToTwoDigits(decimal Value)
{
    int adjusted = (int)Math.Truncate(Value * 100m);
    return adjusted / 100m;
}
```

As a side note, `Math.Truncate` returns the truncated value, it doesn't change the input parameter as your code would imply.

Comment: Wow, that worked, and not too hard to understand but at a good level for me . Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 2):

Math.Truncate like all the other Math function returns the value after the function is called. The function doesn't alter your variable. Actually this was not possible with doubles (please see ref parameters). So you need to do:

```
totalprice = Math.Truncate(totalprice);
```

please notice that totalprice will have just the integer part so if the value is 45.985 the result is 45 so you need to multiply by 100 and then divide. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7d101hyf.aspx

The rounding up that you get there is because console.Write calls String.Format that will do that. See http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-double/ to get your write function call.

Comment: Wait, I thought code like "this.Close();" was called a method, which is a verb. Oh. And then you make a Method/Function out of the Main right? I got a lot to learn :<

Answer (score 0):

Modulo works too. (It's hard to say which is better for safety, readability, and performance.)

```
Decimal totalprice = (sum - 8m) * 0.60m;  // Discount $8.00 and then 40%.
totalprice -= totalprice % 0.01;  // Truncate to two decimal places.
```

Similar question at [Truncate Two decimal places without rounding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3143657/truncate-two-decimal-places-without-rounding)