# View render extra decimal places

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm developing a ASP.NET MVC 4 application and I'm still a newbie for MVC. I noticed view render extra decimal places when I use Html.TextBox as follows.

```
    @Html.TextBox("OriginalContractAmt", Model == null ? 0 : Model.OriginalContractAmt, new { @readonly = true })
```

OriginalContractAmt property is a NotMapped field in the model and view shows the value as 479.4000.

I would like to force it to two decimal places. i.e. 479.40. How do I archive it? Tried following in the model and it didn't make any difference.

```
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:0.0#}")]
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "Also Model.OriginalContractAmt contains the expected value which is 479.4" - how have you checked that? (If it's via the immediate window, I suspect that may be at fault.)

Comment: I checked the value via watch window at both controller & view.

Comment: My guess is that the value really *is* 479.4000m, but the watch window is truncating it. What happens if you call `Model.OriginalContractAmt.ToString()` in the watch window?

Comment: Model.OriginalContractAmt.ToString() returns 479.4000. so I was wrong about it. is there any global fix which can force the views to show only two decimal places?

Comment: At that point, I'm out of my depth, I'm afraid. Happy that I moved the problem along a bit though - I suggest you edit your question appropriately.

Comment: The [DisplayFormat] attribute is only used in EditorFor/DisplayFor, and not by the raw HTML APIs like TextBoxFor.Try with Editor/EditorFor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Math.Round() to round the figure to 2 decimal places.

like:

```
@Html.TextBox("OriginalContractAmt", Model == null ? 0 : Math.Round(Model.OriginalContractAmt,2), new { @readonly = true })
```

If you don't want to round up or round down, then you can use truncate, as worked out by [Hans Passant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17034/hans-passant) in here :

[Truncate Two decimal places without rounding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3143657/truncate-two-decimal-places-without-rounding)

Answer (score 1):

You could update like this, though it feels a bit like a hack:

```
@Html.TextBox("OriginalContractAmt", Model == null ? 0 : Decimal.Round(Model.OriginalContractAmt, 2), new { @readonly = true })
```

I'm assuming rounding would be fine, since you would lose the precision on postback, anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You're specifying the wrong mask:

- 0 is compulsory digit
- # is optional digit

So, the decimals places in this mask `{0:0.0#}` are:

- 0: 1 compulsory decimal place
- #: 1 optional decimal place

So, your mask should be `{0:0.00}`, i.e. two compulsory decimal places.