# Ultragrid column formatting

Tags: c#, .net, infragistics, ultrawingrid

I have set the following format for ultragrid column :

```
ultraGrid.DisplayLayout.Bands[0].Columns[0].Format = "0.####";
```

Now this rounds off the data. Rather I want it truncated.
eg
99.99999999 => 99.9999
and not
99.9999999 => 100

Comment: Note that this also means that `1.4 = 1.3999`, if the type is a double.

Comment: Have you set tye Style property of the column?

Answer (score 0):

The display is how .NET displays the value with the format string and you would get the same result using the format string outside of the grid.  The rounding is documented in the [Custom Numeric Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) topic on MSDN.

As far as approaches to change display the numbers as desired in .NET you can refer to the following questions:

- [.Net: number.ToString without rounding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33337453/net-number-tostring-without-rounding)
- [Truncate Two decimal places without rounding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3143657/truncate-two-decimal-places-without-rounding)

For these approaches to work with the grid it would be best to update the values in the data source the grid is bound to.