# .Net: number.ToString without rounding

Tags: .net, formatting

```
Dim number = 5.678
Console.WriteLine(number.ToString("#,##0.##"))
```

displays `5.68`. Is there any number format string without rounding it?

UPDATE: desired result is `5.67`

Comment: call .ToString() without passing any argument. double x= 3.1415973;
Console.WriteLine(x.ToString())

Comment: Since you don't provide the desired result, we'll have to do some guessing. Do you want the value _truncated_ to two decimal places? The full precision available from the vague data type? Something else?

Comment: @HABO: I'm sure it's more like truncate, but using format string, not function eg. `Math.Truncate`

Comment: If you override `ToString()` and add formatting support for a dagger (`†`) to indicate where to truncate a value and a double dagger (`‡`) to indicate where to _floor_ the value (so that negative values never decrease in absolute value) ... . In short, neither [standard](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) nor [custom](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) numeric format strings support truncation.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Console.Write(Math.Truncate(number * 100) / 100);
```

This should work. Read more answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3143657/truncate-two-decimal-places-without-rounding)

Comment: I'm looking for a way using `.ToString()` function, ie. number format just like in my question.

Answer (score 0):

If you always have to truncate till 2 places, you can use:

```
Console.WriteLine("{0:F2}", number - 0.005);
```

Otherwise you can change number '0.005' as per your need.

Update: If you want to treat this as string, I don't think there is any readymade solution in C#, so you might have to do some extra work like below(You can create a helper method):

```
const double number = 5.678; //input number
var split = number.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Split('.');
Console.WriteLine(split[0] + (split.Length > 1 ? "." : "") + (split.Length > 1 ? split[1].Substring(0, split[1].Length > 1 ? 2 : split[1].Length) : ""));
```

Input: 5.678;
Output: 5.67;

---

Input: 5.6325;
Output: 5.63;

---

Input: 5.64;
Output: 5.64

---

Input: 5.6;
Output: 5.6;

---

input: 585.6138
output: 585.61

Comment: CMIIW. This still rounds the number, and the workaround is subtracting the number with 0.005, right?

Comment: Yes it rounds. But it is easier solution and provides you expected output in all cases. If you must treat it like string you can refer to my updated answer.

Comment: I'm sorry maybe it's my mistake in question. What I mean about using `ToString()` is using it with string format, eg. `ToString("#,##0.##")`, not treating the number as string.

Answer (score 0):

I'm really surprised that not default functionality. This is basically ATP answer except his puts commas between the thousands place.

```
int precision = 2;
string format = "0.##";
decimal rounder = 5.0m/(decimal) Math.Pow(10, precision + 1);
var result = (5.678m - rounder).ToString(format); // This doesn't work for a value of 0m
```

One line:

`result = (5.678m - 5.0m / (decimal)Math.Pow(10, 2 + 1)).ToString("0.##");`