# How to show database values as it is in Asp.Net MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

In my database, values are save in four digits after decimal (`datatype = decimal(19,4))` and when I want to show it those values in the view I only show two digits after decimal. I used format string `{0:F}` to show only two digits after decimal. Now I have an issue when I have a values like `1.9988` it automatically round it to `2.00`. How can I show exact values as in database just truncating last two digits?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Truncate Two decimal places without rounding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3143657/truncate-two-decimal-places-without-rounding)

Answer (score 0):

if you want 4 digits you need to tell it how many... use `{0:F4}`

This is an extension method I use for decimal values that allow me to truncate to a designated number of characters:

```
public static string TruncateToDecimalString( this decimal value , int numberOfDecimals )
{
    int power = (int)Math.Pow( 10 , numberOfDecimals );
    return ( Math.Truncate( value * power ) / power ).ToString( "F" + numberOfDecimals.ToString() );
}
```

Comment: I want to show only two digits for e.g  `1.9998 to 1.99`

Comment: @Lakhae How about `{0:F2}`?

Comment: For that, I don't know of a straight format block: but this does it as a method:
public static string TruncateToDecimalString( this decimal value , int numberOfDecimals )
  {
   int power = (int)Math.Pow( 10 , numberOfDecimals );
   return ( Math.Truncate( value * power ) / power ).ToString( "F" + numberOfDecimals.ToString() );
  }

Answer (score 0):

```
public static decimal TruncateDecimal(double value, int precision)
{
    decimal step = (decimal)Math.Pow(10, precision);
    int tmp = (int)Math.Truncate(step * (decimal)value);
    return tmp / step;
}
```

usage:
decimal result = TruncateDecimal(123.4567, 2);

Example:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZtazLn

Taken from here:
[Truncate Two decimal places without rounding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3143657/truncate-two-decimal-places-without-rounding)

Comment: why this answer received -1?

Comment: Answers should *contain* the answer, not just link to it.  If either of those links ever goes away, the answer becomes useless.  Including a DotNetFiddle is great, but the answer should include the code.  Also, by linking to another question you've found a duplicate.  So this question should be closed as a duplicate anyway.