# Showing only 2 digits after decimal

Tags: decimal, digits

I want my code to show only 2 digits after the decimal, I will show you my code for calculations

```
public class CalculatorModel
{
  private double sbdValue;

  public void addTwoNumbers(double multiplier, double nbd, double sbd)
  {
    sbdValue = nbd * 1.25;
  }

  public double sbdValue()
  {
    return sbdValue;
  }
}
```

Comment: Which language are you using?  Most will have string formatting methods to handle this.

Comment: Looks like Java to me

Comment: Could just as easily be C# or just about any other object oriented language.

Comment: in the answer I use 
     public void setCalcSolution(double solution)
     {
      sofNBD1.setText(Double.toString(solution));
     }

Comment: possible duplicate of [Truncate Two decimal places without rounding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3143657/truncate-two-decimal-places-without-rounding)

Answer (score 0):

You may use one on these options, based on your language:

Java:

```
public double sbdValue()
{
   return Math.round(sbdValue * 100.0) / 100.0
}
```

C#

```
public double sbdValue()
{
   return Math.Round(sbdValue, 2);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, but this is rounding 114.9956 to be 115, is there another way to keep it 114.99 ?

Comment: Sorry I just fixed it, I just missed something Math.Round(sbdValue, 2); I assumed you're using c#, aren't you? @AboelmagdSaadAboelmagd

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what is C# , i'm very new to java world.
The code you wrote with 2 also didn't work unfortunately :(

Comment: C# is another programming language (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp_(programming_language)). Try the solution in Java, It works, I think you're doing something wrong, but you can also try these alternatives  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/153724/how-to-round-a-number-to-n-decimal-places-in-java