# Convert decimal with comma and floating point

Tags: c#

i want to parse like:

```
3.5 -> 3.5
3.484 -> 3.48
3.82822 -> 3.82
```

etc.
However,

```
decimal.Parse("3.543")
```

yields 3543 and
so i did:

```
decimal.Parse("3.543",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

yields 3.543 and
but

```
decimal.Parse(String.Format("{0:0.00}","3.543"),CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

yields 3543

so how can i do it???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need Round method:

```
decimal t = 3.82822;
decimal.Round(t, 2);
```

Where 2 show the decimal points you need.

Answer (score 1):

Use Math.Round like this:

```
decimal a = 1.9946456M;

Math.Round(a, 2); //returns 1.99

decimal b = 1.9953454M;

Math.Round(b, 2); //returns 2.00
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to truncate the decimal places after two digits. Give [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3143657/truncate-two-decimal-places-without-rounding) a try:

```
public decimal TruncateDecimal(decimal value, int precision)
{
    decimal step = (decimal)Math.Pow(10, precision);
    int tmp = (int)Math.Truncate(step * value);
    return tmp / step;
}

decimal t = 3.82822;
decimal d = TruncateDecimal(t, 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a culture that actually uses a comma as a decimal seperator.

```
CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("fr-fr")
```

for example.

```
 Console.WriteLine(decimal.Parse("3,543", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)); // 3543
 Console.WriteLine(decimal.Parse("3,543", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("fr-fr"))); //3,543
```

and if you want to round the result. You could use

```
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0:0.00}", decimal.Parse("3,543", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("fr-fr")))); //3,54
```

Comment: but i want as a result 3,54 and not 3,543 (only 2 digits after the comma)

Comment: then, it would be decimal.Round(decimal.Parse("3,543", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("fr-fr"))),2)