# Round decimal number to smaller number

Tags: c#, decimal, .net-core, .net-standard

With [Decimal.Round](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal.round?view=netcore-2.0#System_Decimal_Round_System_Decimal_System_Int32_System_MidpointRounding_), I can only choose between `ToEven` and `AwayFromZero`, now I'd like to round it always to the smaller number, that is, like truncating, remove the digits that is out of the required decimals:

```
public static void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0,-10} {1,-10} {2,-10}", "Value", "ToEven", "AwayFromZero");
    for (decimal value = 12.123451m; value <= 12.123459m; value += 0.000001m)
        Console.WriteLine("{0} -- {1} -- {2}", value, Math.Round(value, 5, MidpointRounding.ToEven),
                       Math.Round(value, 5, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero));
}

// output
12.123451 -- 12.12345 -- 12.12345
12.123452 -- 12.12345 -- 12.12345
12.123453 -- 12.12345 -- 12.12345
12.123454 -- 12.12345 -- 12.12345
12.123455 -- 12.12346 -- 12.12346
12.123456 -- 12.12346 -- 12.12346
12.123457 -- 12.12346 -- 12.12346
12.123458 -- 12.12346 -- 12.12346
12.123459 -- 12.12346 -- 12.12346
```

I just want all those to be rounded to `12.12345`, that is keep 5 decimals, and truncating remaining ones. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Truncate Two decimal places without rounding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3143657/truncate-two-decimal-places-without-rounding)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
decimal.Truncate(value * (decimal)Math.Pow(10, 5)) / (decimal)Math.Pow(10, 5);
```

or simply

```
decimal.Truncate(value * 100000) / 100000;
```

should solve your problem by shifting the value 5 digits left, truncating and shifting the 5 digits back.

Example in 4 steps:

1. 1.23456 `* 100000`
2. 12345.6 `decimal.Truncate`
3. 12345 `/ 100000`
4. 1.2345

Not as much simple as the first approach but at least twice as fast at my device is using a string and split it. Here is my implementation:

```
string[] splitted = value.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Split('.');
string newDecimal = splitted[0];
if (splitted.Length > 1)
{
    newDecimal += ".";
    newDecimal += splitted[1].Substring(0, Math.Min(splitted[1].Length, 5));
}
decimal result = Convert.ToDecimal(newDecimal, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: Thanks, this will produce the right result I want. But this involves multiple arithmetic operations, I'm doing this for a fast data stream, so is there anyway to optimize this further?

Comment: I've added a much faster implementation using strings to my answer @fluter

Comment: I will try this, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Math.Floor`, if you modify the decimal places before you use it, and then return back to the original position like this:

```
public static decimal RoundDown(decimal input, int decimalPlaces)
{
    decimal power = (decimal) Math.Pow(10, decimalPlaces);
    return Math.Floor(input * power) / power;
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hZJRT8IwEMef209x2VMnOJnK09DEQDQmmBAl8cH4MLcTm5SWtB3EIJ8du27DgRj3cuv17v//9XKZOc2Uxm1huJzB06exOE9o@xQNlRCYWa6kie5QouZZsl0Ub4JnkInUGJhoNdPpnK4pqfPGptaFpeI5PKRcspCSNSEUWp9WhcxHaiWnaCwLE0o2lBxVOKh0UpSQ@zE3dpBjxuepuAbrrsoMXIHEFexdenEnTYzV5cPSPJ9jmXpXGhiXFqRr6yUuDCAuY6fjXLwN8cXuOojPo/j84rIfQAdk2U0az@gmz9lQySVqG03VqLJlvjP03pvK/4DZv@tf6GOQO@ehk7D7wDtVjwWPzfBY0/QiX7v9ENpgDt4ogdGz5hbHXCILlOYzLlMB8FWBYh6Efw3tx/MI0G/xFokbZuAcyqHuRFy6BXdkK@oZtd7WZLhcFLYLJV6dmog0Q1MvTVO2UCvUDr/pC92W2o9oolYs7nUPWksUjbbQsqq6FUpp5p3gpJIK4az6abaYbrbbbw)

Answer (score 0):

Are you perhaps instead looking for `Math.Floor`?

> Floor(Decimal)
> Returns the largest integer less than or equal to the specified decimal number.
>
> Floor(Double)
> Returns the largest integer less than or equal to the specified double-precision floating-point number.

Comment: No, I'm not looking for Floor, I'm not for the nearest integer, rather nearest float point number with specified precision.