# Displaying 2 Decimal places in Datagridview without rounding off

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a `Datagridview` that allows user to input the prices of a product. My client wants it that if I enter 2.525 in the price, it will display 2.52 and when I focus or edit the cell it should display the full vale of 2.525.

I am using this code in formatting the `Datagridview` Columns but this one is rounding off the entered value and it does not display the whole value when the cell is in editing mode because i am using C2.

`CustInvLines.Columns["InvLinePrice"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = C2`

How will I format the cell so that it will display the whole value entered by user in edit mode and It will only display 2 decimal places after editing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should format value by yourself in `DataGridView.CellFormatting` event handler

```
private void CustInvLines_CellFormatting(object sender,
                                         DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.RowIndex < 0)
    {
        return;
    }
    var column = CustInvLines.Columns[e.ColumnIndex];
    if (column.Name == "InvLinePrice")
    {
        var cell = CustInvLines.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex];
        var value = (decimal)e.Value;
        if (cell.IsInEditMode)
        {
            e.Value = value.ToString(); // Display all digits
        }
        else
        {
            // Display only two digits of decimals without rounding
            var twoDigitsValue = Math.Truncate(value * 100)/100;
            e.Value = twoDigitsValue.ToString("C2");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried it but i am getting an error `Specified cast is not valid` in the line `var value = (decimal)e.Value;`. I already tried to change it to `var value = Convert.ToDecimal(e.Value);` but the same error.

Comment: Are you sure that underlying value is of type `decimal`?

Comment: Additional to checking for column name, you should add a criteria to check `e.RowIndex > -1`.

Comment: @Zhyke, check updated answer, as suggested in above comments, you should check for header row

Comment: @Fabio yap. Actually when i hover the `e.Value`, the value is 12.

Comment: @RezaAghaei & Fabio thanks to both of you, that's solve the issue.

Comment: Hello, sorry i still got an error but anyway i manged to handle it. I just added a condition to check if the row is a newrow. ` if(e.RowIndex != CustInvLines.NewRowIndex)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this on `CellEndEdit` events on the `DataGridView`.

```
private void CustInvLines_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
        var column = CustInvLines.Columns[e.ColumnIndex];
        if (column.Name == "InvLinePrice")
        {
            var val = CustInvLines.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value;
            if (val !=null)
            {
                var twoDecimal = Math.Truncate(100 * decimal.Parse(val.ToString())) / 100;
                CustInvLines.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value = twoDecimal.ToString("C2");
            }  
        }
}
```

There answers in this question will give you information about [Truncate Two decimal places without rounding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3143657/truncate-two-decimal-places-without-rounding).