# How can I display and use multiple whole numbers and only 2 decimal places on a calculator?

Tags: c#, decimal, calculator

I am working on a calculator in Visual Studio 2019 and I have had a problem.
I need to multiply a variable value (let's call it X) by a constant one (let's call it Y = 400).
The value X is obtained after doing another mathematical operation, but it shows an exaggerated number of decimal places that when multiplying by Y is incorrect.

Suppose I get X = 1.47857142857143. I only need the first 2 decimals (.47) and whatever integer that results.

Incorrect result: 1.47857142857143 * 400 = 591.4285

Correct result: 1.47 * 400 = 588.

As final data:
1.- I have to use the result for other operations; so hiding it with the margins of the label or the textbox does not work for me.
2.-I only have knowledge of the C++ language and using C#, but many years have passed since I used them, so I would appreciate it if the answers were as detailed as possible.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Truncate Two decimal places without rounding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3143657/truncate-two-decimal-places-without-rounding)

Comment: You're in control. Consider writing down all the rules of your calculator (for example: always _truncate_ `X` to two decimal places). Then figure out how to implement the rules (like following the link from @Henry). Get the rules right and the software should follow.

Answer (score 0):

That is wrong first question for your problem. First you should decide  that what is the max digits for your X,  and result.  I think Y is always integer. If X have max 4 digits and result have max 2 digits , your result always goes to wrong  mathematically. First pls check Math.Round