# Formating string

Tags: .net, string

how can I format this string to 2 places after dot in .NET:

My string: 224.39000000000001
What I want to get: 224.39

Also it has to be a String. I don't want to parse it or convert it

I've tried with:

```
String.Format(Data[i].Number, "%.2f")
```

but it does not working

Comment: `String. Format("{0:0.##}", your_string)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Truncate Two decimal places without rounding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3143657/truncate-two-decimal-places-without-rounding)

Comment: No, non of solution works

Comment: You cannot format a string as if it was a number, you will need to find another method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your "Number" property is of type string, then you cannot format it as a number. Either convert it to a number and then format, OR find the position of the `.` and use a substring:

```
var s = "224.39000000000001";
var i = s.IndexOf('.');
if (i >= 0  && i < s.Length-2)
{
  // found a '.' so just use up to that + 2 extra characters
  Console.WriteLine(s.Substring(0, i+3));
}
else
{
  // no '.' found, so just take all
  Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

You can of course wrap this in a method returning the trimmed string, so you can call it from anywhere.

**EDIT**
Also guard against less than 2 characters after the `.`, such as "244.4".