# Remove last decimal value

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to remove the last decimal point from a floating value but I am not sure how to do this. For example: 3.567, I want the result to be 3.56.

I am trying to do this but it rounds off the value, that is, the value changes to 3.40 instead. I do not want this. How do I solve it to remove the last or 3rd decimal value ?

```
float value = 3.567f;
value = Mathf.Round (value * 10f) * 0.1f;
```

Comment: Instead of `Round` you may use `Floor`, which will return the down-rounded value.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Truncate Two decimal places without rounding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3143657/truncate-two-decimal-places-without-rounding)

Comment: Might want to use `Mathf.Floor`

Comment: Did not know about Floor. That works well. Thank you :)