# How to Format Decimal/Round Numbers on RDLC

Tags: rdlc

Good Day!

I need some idea on how can I format the final value with (2) decimal places/round off of code below.

```
 =Count(Fields!rClosedDate.Value) / Count(Fields!PostDate.Value) * 100 & "%"
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify a format for numeric values using the Format property of the TextBox.

Examples of formatting string (full list [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252080%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)):

- c: currency
- d: decimal
- p: percentage

To specify 2 decimal places you can set a formatting string like this: `p2`

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39305134/2218697) is my answer to set 3 decimal places  without rounding off , is that correct ?